# chrome - iOS 7 - iPhone: select form element's spinner's background is black

Tags: ios, css, google-chrome, ios7

iPhone on iOS 7 with it's lovely translucency everywhere is wonderful.

Except in chrome when you have a select element near the bottom of the page. 
The options spinner has no content to be transparent over and so is transparent over black.

I've made a simplified case http://jsfiddle.net/bXMkb/6/

```
   <div class="push"></div>
   <select ...

   html, body { height: 100%; background:orange; }  
   .push { height:90%; }
```

[image]

Safari uses white rather than black and that works nicely, so clearly it's changeable at the native level, does anyone know of a way to set the background colour of the outside of the document? possibly with a meta tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is likely the implementation of the Chrome for iOS. Spinner control is part of the native UI in this case. Which means it follows the tint property of the UIView.

As far as I know, no meta tag exist for Chrome that will change the tint behavior.